# Module not found : Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-challenge\sample\src'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am learning react from a playlist and had created a basic app with create-react-app it was up and running without any issues initially. After I deleted some files in *'**src**'* and *'**public**'* ,the terminal is showing this error:

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-challenge\sample\src'
```

I deleted everything except for ***'index.html'*** in public and ***'index.js'*** in src file. I have attached the folder structure and index.js below.

[image: This is my current folder structure]

[image: This is my index.js code]

EDIT: it was an issue regarding the files getting saved and reloading it is solved now.

Comment: You are not supposed to delete App.js file.

Comment: @zx01 I believe we can delete the app.js file , for the react app to work it is just necessary for return a component which I am doing it here as a function. And thank you for responding, it was an issue from my side as I was not saving it, after saving it is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to delete App.js if you're not using it, and it looks like you're not.
You probably just need to restart your development server.

Stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
Start it again with `npm start` or `yarn start`

Comment: it was an issue with the files not getting saved, now it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

power off your code editor and start again the code editor then run npm start in the terminal